# Need help building Reactive Form of Radio Input List

Tags: javascript, angular, output, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I want to realize my selection with reactive Forms, i am new to this so here is my code:

I already tried to implement it with the documentation and the provided examples, but with no luck and destoying my single select radio button selection input. What do i need to implement in my .ts file and here in my html snippet to realize that?

Here is my working HTML Snippet:

```
<div *ngFor="let stream of myList">
    <label>
      {{ stream.sys }}
    </label>
    <p *ngFor="let type of stream.types">
      <tr>
        <input type="radio" name="nav"/>
        {{ type.type.label }}
      </tr>
    </p>
  </div>
```

I am looping over the outer list and the inner list with input Type radio. Everything works fine. Now i want to implement it to be Reactive Forms:

This is my desired Output for example:

```
Test
 o Number 1
Test2
 o Number 10
 o Number 20
Test3
 X Number 100

Value: Number 100 // or some id i have in my input data -> type.type.id
```

This navigation needs to be a select of one item and i want to show the form value unter my list as first step.

I tried something like this:

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let stream of myList">
    <label>
      {{ stream.sys }}
    </label>
    <p *ngFor="let type of stream.types">
      <tr>
        <input type="radio" name="name" formControlName="name" />
        {{ type.type.label }}
      </tr>
    </p>
  </div>
</form>

<p>
    Value: {{ form.value | json}}
</p>
```

**.ts**

```
form: FormGroup;
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = formBuilder.group({
    name: ['']
  });
```

Comment: Hi, it's a bit confusing as to what you're asking. You say you want it to be a single select but you're still using a radio button in your example. Please can you clarify?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward I meant a complete form for all radio buttons, single select was a bit confusing i guess. I adpated it I want just one selectable in my complete List. This is working with my example above. I think my form control is missing a value decorator...?

Comment: Do you have a stackblitz example of this? It's quite hard to judge this without seeing the data that's coming in.

Comment: you need give some value to your radio [value]="..." `<input type="radio" name="name" [value]="type.type.value" formControlName="name" />`

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for your answer, i got it by myself a little bit different, but yours is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Your looping on myList. The formBuilder should contain an array of groups. And every single group should contain a 'name' control. 'value' should not be needed. And If you want to preset something you can set it in the formbuilder.
2. This is not related to the problem but I dont think the `<tr>` is incorrect in a `<p>`. Instead you could just add the loop on a div instead of a paragraph and then remove the tablerow

Comment: Jens, he is using radiobuttons, it's only a FormControl, not an Form Array

Comment: Still there is a outer loop myList inside the form. Lets say that it has count 3. And the inner list stream.types has count 5. The html templet will add 15 radiobutton inputs with duplications. I just guessed that the out loop myList was ment to correspond dynamic rows in the form. Then you would need an array with a group within.

Comment: Yes I think my guess is correct. There is a label for every 'row' {{ stream.sys }} so its a dynamic form. Looping the 'form rows'. We dont know how many 'rows' myList contains so then you need to use a FormArray. To make the reactive form model correspond to the html template